# Eliminar elementos de una lista en Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

tengo una lista en la que voy guardando números según el usuario los va introduciendo, entonces me gustaría que cuando el usuario introduzca un número que ya esté en la lista este se borre y no sé cómo hacerlo.

La lista es así e introduzco los números de este modo:

```
var _numeros = new List(6);

_numeros[i] = numero;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que esto puede solucionar tu problema, basicamente lo que hace el codigo es buscar el valor que le das y si lo encuentra lo va a quitar, de lo contrario puedes insertar el nuevo valor sin problema.

```
List<int> _numeros = List(6);
_numeros[0] = 1;
_numeros[1] = 2;
_numeros[2] = 3;
_numeros[3] = 4;
_numeros[4] = 5;

int _valor = 1;
if (_numeros.contains(_valor)) {
  _numeros.remove(_valor);
} else {
  _numeros.add(_valor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Repasa el metodo contains del objeto List para saber si un elemento esta contenido en la lista
[contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/contains.html)

y el metodo remove si tienes que eliminar un elemento de la lista.

[remove](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/remove.html)

Comment: Pero contains retorna un true, ¿cómo sé luego qué elemento he de borrar?

Answer (score 0):

contains retorna true si el elemento que tu le pasas por parametro ya existe en la lista(si no existe retorna false).Si retorna true quiere decir que ese elemento que tu le pasas ya esta en la lista y tiene que ser borrado, segun has dicho,luego para borrarlo,le pasas ese mismo elemento al metodo remove(mira el ejemplo de remove)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el método `List.removeWhere()` es lo que buscas.

```
  var numbers = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4];
  print(numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  
  void addNewNumber(int number) {
    numbers.removeWhere((element) => (element == number));
    numbers.add(number);
  }
  
  addNewNumber(1);
  print(numbers); // [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Para más información: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html